# In Table Tennis, does a 7-0 lead mean that set is won?

Tags: rules, table-tennis, scoring

Suppose we are playing a match/set for 11 points with 2 serves each. If one team get a lead of 7-0, does that mean that the team won that match/set?
What is the case for a match/set for 21 points? 11-0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing happens (officially).

According to the ITTF [Rules](https://d3mjm6zw6cr45s.cloudfront.net/2018/01/2018ITTFHandbook.pdf):

> 2.11 A Game
>
> A game shall be won by the player or pair first scoring **11 points**
> unless both players  or  pairs  score  10  points,  when  the  game
> shall  be  won  by  the  first player or pair subsequently gaining a
> lead of 2 points.

In unofficial matches there may be a so-called **mercy rule** (or skunk rule), which may end a game after a 7-0 lead or other standings. Since no official rule about this exists any longer the requirements may vary.

The USATT also has some extra [basement rules](http://www.usatt.net/rules/basementRules.html) (they're not real rules!) which still include a skunk rule:

> 12.1 Scores of 7-0, 11-1, 15-2, and 21-3 are game winning "skunks". As if being "skunked" isn't bad enough, the skunkee may also be
> required to perform push ups or drink two beers.
>
> 12.2 The loser of a game is required to drink a beer. In the event of a "skunk" the loser must drink two beers.